# How to remove unknown slits when using filledcurve in Gnuplot (epslatex)?

Tags: latex, gnuplot, eps

I'm now trying to use `filledcurve` in gnuplot 4.6, patchlevel 1. Following shows the sample script:

```
set term epslatex
set output "figure.tex"

set xlabel "\\huge{x-axis}"
set ylabel "\\huge{y-axis}"
set format xy "\\LARGE{%.0f}"
set xrange [0.0:10.0]
set yrange [0.0:100.0]
set xtics 2.0
set ytics 20.0
set xtics offset 0, -0.3

f1(x) = x**1
f2(x) = x**2
f3(x) = x**3

set nokey
plot '+' using 1:(f2($1)):(f3($1)) with filledcurve lt 1 lc rgb "gray60",\
     '+' using 1:(f1($1)):(f2($1)) with filledcurve lt 1 lc rgb "gray40",\
     '+' using 1:(0.0):(f1($1))    with filledcurve lt 1 lc rgb "gray20"
```

I don't known why, but it seems that there are white annoying slits between bars. It cannot be get rid of even if I increase the number of `set samples`.

Is there any idea to remove these slits?

[image]

Comment: I have noticed this as well, but it seems to be a problem related to displaying the figure rather than a gnuplot problem. Maybe this display issue is triggered by how gnuplot generates the figure, that I do not know. If you import your eps file with GIMP, for instance, the white lines will be gone. Also, it does not have an effect when printing.

Comment: Thanks, @Miguel. I have also checked that the lines do not exist when using "evince" (which is a linux command for displaying eps figures), and also when printing. However, if I put the eps figure into the latex file, the lines appear again.

Comment: When I built a dvi file using `latex` and your script, the lines where gone, then came back when exporting to PDF using `dvipdf`. Perhaps if you fiddle a bit with the options passed to `dvipdf` you can prevent this from happening (I do not know), or use some different utility such as `dvipdfmx` or so. I will try and have a look when I get the chance, since I'm interested in this myself.

Comment: See the bug report http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1259/ for a related discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a viewer problem related to the drawing of adjacent filled polygons, see also [problematic Moire pattern in image produced with gnuplot pm3d and pdf output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927493/problematic-moire-pattern-in-image-produced-with-gnuplot-pm3d-and-pdf-output) or the bug report [#1259 cairolatex pdf fill patterns](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1259/).

In your case you can use a workaround:

When you have only two columns in the `using` statement, the area is drawn as closed polygon and doesn't show these artifacts (`filledcurves closed`). So you must fill the area between each curve and the `x1` axis (with `filledcurves x1`).

Because of a bug in the clipping of curves which exceed the y-range, you must do the clipping of the `f3` curve yourself (i.e. use `f3($1) > 100 ? 100 : f3($1)`). This bug is fixed in the development version.

So you script is:

```
set term epslatex standalone
set output "figure.tex"

set xlabel "\\huge x-axis"
set ylabel "\\huge y-axis"
set format xy "\\LARGE %.0f"
set xrange [0.0:10.0]
set yrange [0.0:100.0]
set xtics 2.0
set ytics 20.0
set xtics offset 0, -0.3

f1(x) = x**1
f2(x) = x**2
f3(x) = x**3

set nokey
plot '+' using 1:(f3($1) > 100 ? 100 : f3($1)) with filledcurve x1 lt 1 lc rgb "gray60",\
     '+' using 1:(f2($1)) with filledcurve x1 lt 1 lc rgb "gray40",\
     '+' using 1:(f1($1)) with filledcurve x1 lt 1 lc rgb "gray20"

set output
system('latex figure.tex && dvips figure.dvi && ps2pdf figure.ps')
```

with the result (using 4.6.1):

[image]

Note also, that LaTeX commands like `\huge` don't take arguments, but are switches. Test e.g. `\huge{A}BC`, this will make all letter huge. Usually you must limit the scope of `\huge` with brackets like `{\huge ABC}`, but if the whole label is affected, it is enough to use `set xlabel "\\huge x-axis"`. That doesn't change anything in your case, but may give you troubles in other circumstances :)

Comment: Thanks, @Christoph! It worked, and it is perfect solution for me.

Comment: and, also thank you for your advice about the LaTeX command. :)