# How to fill a rectangle with colors of visible spectrum in gnuplot?

Tags: colors, gnuplot

How to draw a rectangle filled by visual spectrum color in rectangle in a graph?

[image]
The rectangle would we plotted like:

set object 1 rectangle from first 6545, graph 0 to first 6580, graph 1 fillcolor "????"

I found the color in this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208769/visible-spectrum-with-gnuplot).

How to do that please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple, quick and dirty approach (still to be tuned) would be the following if you just need a rough impression of the color. Make sure that `set samples` is set high enough such that you have enough `impulses` and don't get white (background) lines.
If you need this spectrum in another graph create an inset with `multiplot` by adjusting `origin` and `size`. Check this in gnuplot with `help multiplot`,  `help origin` and `help size`

However, if you need more precise color representation, check the links at the link you gave.

**Code:**

```
### visible spectrum ("quick and dirty")
reset session

set palette defined (380 "black", 400 "dark-violet", 440 "blue",  490 '#00b0c0', 530 "green", 560 "yellow", 620 "red", 780 "black")

set samples 1000
unset colorbox

plot [380:780] '+' u 1:(1):1 w impulse lc palette notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

Maybe something like this:

**Code:**

```
### visible spectrum ("quick and dirty")
# inserted into another plot
reset session

set palette defined (380 "black", 400 "dark-violet", 440 "blue",  490 '#00b0c0', 530 "green", 560 "yellow", 620 "red", 780 "black")

set samples 1000
unset colorbox

set multiplot 
    plot cos(x)+0.2*x

    set origin 0.05,0.75
    set size 0.45, 0.2
    unset tics
    plot [380:780] '+' u 1:(1):1 w impulse lc palette lw 1 notitle

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Another variation:

**Code:**

```
### visible spectrum ("quick and dirty")
# below curve
reset session

set palette defined (380 "black", 400 "dark-violet", 440 "blue",  490 '#00b0c0', 530 "green", 560 "yellow", 620 "red", 780 "black")

set samples 1000
unset colorbox

f(x) = sin((x-380)/25)*cos((x-580)/10) + 2

plot [380:780] '+' u 1:(f(x)):1 w impulse lc palette notitle, \
     f(x) w l lw 2 lc rgb "black" notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much and how to connect it with another graph? Is there easier way than multiplot?