# filledcurve with terminal pdf looks bad

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, gnuplot

There is a beautiful script producing a rectangle with rounded corners here:

http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.de/2011/10/round-corner-rectangle-in-gnuplot.html

It works so far and I'm able to adapt this example to my needs.

The problem is that it does not work properly in case of pdf output and I have no idea why .. there seems to be a problem with pdf and filledcurve in a way, that the area is not properly filled. Viewing the pdf you can clearly see that the filling consists of stripes and in between them are white lines separating them. It looks really bad on screen and on paper.

Again: the problem only occurs if the script is adapted to pdf output!

I've been working on this all day and still no clue how to fix this.

Does anyone see a way out? Or is it an inherent problem of the way curves are filled?

Comment: That seems to be a generic viewer problem with surfaces produces by stitching a lot of polygons together and affects also pm3d, see e.g. [problematic Moire pattern in image produced with gnuplot pm3d and pdf output](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18927493/2604213). In your case a possible workaround could be to manually plot four quarter ellipses and three rectangles.

Comment: Yes, your workaround should do the job .. but unlike 'circle' I can't specify the 'arc' when plotting ellipses .. so I can't see a way to plot quarter ellipses. But maybe I miss something pretty easy.

Comment: If you don't need to use transparency, you can just draw full ellipses.

Comment: Transparency would be nice.