# artifacts in transparent fill when plotting data files with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, transparency, fill

I am plotting a file containing multicolumn data in multiple data blocks. Here is a typical excerpt from the datafile:

```
729.22 5.36 4.36 3.00 7.72
729.32 5.39 4.39 3.00 7.77
729.42 5.41 4.41 3.00 7.82
[...]
745.52 9.63 5.84 5.79 13.47
745.62 9.66 5.82 5.83 13.48

742.74 5.60 4.60 3.00 8.20
742.84 5.61 4.61 3.00 8.22
[...]
```

I am trying to apply transparent fill using

```
set terminal pdf color enhanced font "Times,10" size 4,5 fontscale 0.5
set style fill transparent solid 0.1 noborder
[...]
plot "datafile.txt" index 0 using 1:4:5 with filledcurves lc rgb 'gray60'
```

Not only does the plot show fine-grained vertical "streaking" artifacts, but the filled polygons corresponding to different data blocks appear with different darknesses (I mean the non-overlapping portions of the polygons, of course).

[link to PDF output file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxQd2sgBeo6xbmpzdEp2MEtJNmM/view?usp=sharing)

Can anyone advise me about how to correct these artifacts? They also appear using the pdfcairo terminal. I am running Gnuplot 5.0.1 on OS X 10.10.5. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this on different pdf viewers? It happened to me that evince shows vertical lines on a filled curve, but acroreader shows a clean image. About the different color shading, could it be some kind of illusion? :-)

Comment: The artifacts appear in Adobe Acrobat Pro, Adobe Illustrator and Apple Preview, and are preserved when printed or exported from Illustrator as a PNG.

Comment: This is a known problem, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31350629/2604213