# Using gnuplot, how do you create an eps file of a contour plot?

Tags: gnuplot

Using gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 5, I am trying to create an eps file containing a contour plot. However, the contour lines are accompanied by a grid and do not have the requested color. The output using the png terminal is just fine.

Here is the minimum code I use to generate the eps image:

```
set terminal epscairo
set output "test.eps"
set pm3d map impl
set style increment user
set contour
do for [i=1:5] { set style line i lc rgb "black" lw 3}
splot "data.dat" w pm3d notitle
```

[eps image created by gnuplot with the funny feature around the contour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxXUW.png)

replacing the epscairo terminal by png gives the desired output:

[png image created by gnuplot, this how I would like the eps image to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoIoN.png)

The data file I am using can be found here:
[data.dat](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZABA17Z5552m5o4oGVJwXfaXSv9sV24yh4k)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18954245/2604213 for a detailed explanation of this problem

Comment: I don't think that I have this type of problem. What I see in the eps figure is just an additional grid and change of color of the contour lines, no moiré.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the `epslatex` or `postscript` terminals so you can encode the heat map as a binary in png  (see the `level3` option for both terminals).

Try replacing your first line with the following:

```
set term postscript color eps level3
```

Comment: That option affects only plotting `with image`, but not `pm3d`.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the problem.