# Annoying lines with style filledcurve

Tags: gnuplot

I am using gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 3 and trying to plot a filledcurved generated from a data file. The data file is previously filtered and sorted with the help of awk and sort. A minimal script is

```
 set style fill transparent solid 0.2
 plot "<awk -f awkfile filename|sort -g -k 1" u 1:2 with filledcurve y1=90,'' u 1:2 w points
```

The output fills the curve up to y1=90, which is fine. However every data point is stick with a vertical line runnning from y to y1=90. The line is solid and non-transparent. It ruins the output. How can I get rid of them?

[image: Minimal output. Fill is working fine but the vertical lines going from data points to y1=90 ruins it. How can I get rid of them?]

Comment: I think this issue was fixed in version 5.2, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46541649/2604213. Both artifacts probably have the same origin

Comment: Thank you. Yes it worked fine with 5.2 (I have just installed it for the occassion). Only that I lost the pngcairo terminal I was outputting the ultimate result. Any hint? I tried installing --with-cairo option but it didnot work. (SO ubuntu 16.04LTS)

Comment: I found my way and cairo terminals are available. But then I found the copy of gnuplot can not read png/jgp file. It happens I was reading a jpeg file as a background image.

Comment: Now the copy can read jpg files and the script worked all right. Thank you very much.